# ¿como puedo crear un if que pueda cambiar el valor de un selecta al presionar un botón?

Tags: if

¿Cómo puedo crear un if que pueda cambiar el valor de un select al presionar un botón?

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM pais  WHERE ciudad ='$valor-a-camiar-con-if'";
```

Necesito que sea con un if. ¿Es posible?

Esto sería para un proyecto con php y html

Comment: En qué lenguaje, podrás aclarar un poco más lo que querés hacer? Así evitás que te cierren la pregunta.

Comment: estoy haciendo un ejercicio con php  y html.. gracias es que soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación ..

Comment: Hola @SandroRosario, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: no queda para nada claro lo que quieres hacer estimado, quieres aplicar una función condicional en medio de una query o estas haciendo la query en algun lenguaje y para después ejecutarla?

Comment: Que tal, por lo regular en el mundo de la programación, se maneja en back y front, por lo regular las consultas van en la parte del back, por lo cual lo correcto seria generar una función en la cual envíes tus parámetros por ejemplo ejecutaConsulta(tabla, id), cachar los parámetros en esa función y enviarlos a tu consulta, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

segun veo lo que quieres hacer es que al presionar un boton lleve una informacion ya sea por GET o por POST a un script PHP.

Ahí lo que tendrías que hacer es lo siguiente

```
if($ciudad == 1){
  $ciudad = "xxx";
}
if($ciudad == 2){
  $ciudad = "yyy";
}
else{
$ciudad = "zzz";
}
```

Luego en el query:

```
SELECT * FROM pais WHERE ciudad ='$ciudad';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Puedes conseguirlo mediante el uso de un `if/else if/else` lo cual te
>   va a ayudar primero a verificar el valor de la variable que te esta
>   llegando para que posteriormente pases dicha variable al cuerpo de la
>   consulta y ejecutes la misma

si es por el método `GET;`

```
$ciudad = $_GET['ciudad'];
```

---

o si es por el método `POST;`

---

```
$ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];

if($ciudad === 1){
  $ciudad = 'Mexico';
  $query = "SELECT * FROM pais WHERE ciudad = .'$ciudad'."
}else if($ciudad === 2){
  $ciudad = 'Bogota';
  $query = "SELECT * FROM pais WHERE ciudad = .'$ciudad'."
}else{
  $ciudad = 'Madrid';
  $query = "SELECT * FROM pais WHERE ciudad = .'$ciudad'."
}
```

> Puedes ampliar este encadenamiento de if, else if tantas veces como
>   necesites